# Restore full image from IIIF json

Tags: json, image, url, request, iiif

If we have IIIF `info.json` in the [following format](http://iiif.nli.org.il/IIIF/FL47675519/info.json):

```
{
  "@context" : "http://iiif.io/api/image/2/context.json",
  "@id" : "http://iiif.nli.org.il/IIIF/FL47675519",
  "protocol" : "http://iiif.io/api/image",
  "width" : 6000,
  "height" : 4784,
  "sizes" : [ {
    "width" : 46,
    "height" : 37
  }, {
    "width" : 93,
    "height" : 74
  }, {
    "width" : 187,
    "height" : 149
  }, {
    "width" : 375,
    "height" : 299
  } ],
  "tiles" : [ {
    "width" : 1024,
    "height" : 1024,
    "scaleFactors" : [ 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128 ]
  } ],
  "profile" : [ "http://iiif.io/api/image/2/level1.json", {
    "formats" : [ "jpg" ],
    "qualities" : [ "native", "color", "gray" ],
    "supports" : [ "regionByPct", "regionSquare", "sizeByForcedWh", "sizeByWh", "sizeAboveFull", "rotationBy90s", "mirroring" ]
  } ]
}
```

How can I get all of the image's tiles in a high-quality one after the other?

I observed the browser's request and couldn't find a pattern for legitimate and illegal requests.

These requests are legitimate (to see the images you need first get into [the library website](https://web.nli.org.il/sites/NLI/Hebrew/digitallibrary/pages/viewer.aspx?&presentorid=MANUSCRIPTS&docid=PNX_MANUSCRIPTS990001568050205171-1#%7CFL47675519) and after some zoom-in and zoom-out the next link will work):

- https://iiif.nli.org.il/IIIFv21/FL47675519/0,0,4096,4096/1024,/0/default.jpg
- https://iiif.nli.org.il/IIIFv21/FL47675519/0,4096,4096,688/1024,/0/default.jpg
- https://iiif.nli.org.il/IIIFv21/FL47675519/4096,4096,1904,688/476,/0/default.jpg

However, these are not valid:

- https://iiif.nli.org.il/IIIFv21/FL47675519/4096,4096,1904,688/1024,/0/default.jpg
- https://iiif.nli.org.il/IIIFv21/FL47675519/0,2048,4096,688/1024,/0/default.jpg

So, what should I do to iterate all over the image tiles?

I tried reading the IIIF documentation [here](https://iiif.io/api/image/3.0/#table-of-contents), but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

In your case https://iiif.nli.org.il/IIIFv21/FL47675519/full/max/0/default.jpg
to get it in max. resolution
instead max you can take size: https://iiif.nli.org.il/IIIFv21/FL47675519/full/6000/0/default.jpg